# One or more errors occurred. (Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g))

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Trying to deserialize an array of book objects from the GoogleBook API.

Models: https://pastebin.com/24S16hZc

Confirmed API respons: https://pastebin.com/2q0aFGnf

Booking Page:

```
  public BookingPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        ResizeWindow();
        UpdateListView();

    }

    private void UpdateListView()
    {
        UserList_List.Items.Clear();

        foreach (HelperLibrary.UserObject L in App.GlobalUserList)
        {
            UserList_List.Items.Add($" { L.FirstName } { L.LastName }");

        }

        //Prepare task
        Task<HelperLibrary.Models.GoogleBook.RootObject[] > GetBooksTask = HelperLibrary.Helpers.APIHelper.SearchBooks("Hacker");

        GetBooksTask.Wait();

        HelperLibrary.Models.GoogleBook.RootObject[] Books = GetBooksTask.Result;

        foreach(HelperLibrary.Models.GoogleBook.RootObject P in Books)
        {
            BookList_list.Items.Add(P.volumeInfo.title);
        }


    }
```

API Helper task

```
 public class APIHelper
{
    private static string BaseURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes";

    public static async Task<HelperLibrary.Models.GoogleBook.RootObject[] > SearchBooks(string term)
    {

        using (var WebClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseURL) })
        {

            var ResponseHandler = WebClient.GetAsync($"?q= { term } ");


            if (ResponseHandler.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string x = await ResponseHandler.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Debug.WriteLine(x);
                Models.GoogleBook.RootObject[] items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.GoogleBook.RootObject[]>(await ResponseHandler.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                return items;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }


        }
    }




}
```

Full error:

> JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object
>   (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[HelperLibrary.Models.GoogleBook+RootObject]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
>   .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
>   type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
>   to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'kind', line 2, position 8.

I'm already trying to declare it to an array, not a List?
Been trough most other threads about this, can't seem to find a situation similar to mine.

Comment: i think the problem here is that you are expecting an Array from the json, but based on the json you gave us the root is an object thats why it returns an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood what is the `RootObject`.  What you have defined as such is actually the inner object inside your `RootObject`.

I suggest you do this;

1)   Rename your RootObject to Item

```
    public class Item
    {
        public string kind { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string etag { get; set; }
        public string selfLink { get; set; }
        public VolumeInfo volumeInfo { get; set; }
        public LayerInfo layerInfo { get; set; }
        public SaleInfo saleInfo { get; set; }
        public AccessInfo accessInfo { get; set; }
    }
```

2)  Create a new RootObject

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string kind { get; set; }
    public int totalItems { get; set; }
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}
```

Then your Deserialize should look like this;

```
Models.GoogleBook.RootObject root = 
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.GoogleBook.RootObject>(await ResponseHandler.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, changes implemented and tested working! :)

Answer (score 0):

Checking the structure of the json, i think what you are trying to get is the item array of the json if i am not mistaken. What you can do is Try to create a parent class containing the array Root Object something like this:

```
Public class RootParent
{
    public string kind {get; set;}
    public int totalItems {get;set;}
    public List<RootObject> items {get; set;}
}
```